# I am not able to fire command from menuitem.i have list view.i have not binded any thing

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

below is code behind.code for my simple form

## In My code behind

```
 public MainWindow()
 {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new viewModel();
 }
```

### My view model

```
public class viewModel
 {
   public ICommand TaskmenuCommand = new RelayCommand(_OpenTaskWindow);

       private static void _OpenTaskWindow(object obj)
        {
             /*Some logic for Add,Edit delete*/
        }
 }
```

Below is my front end.simple list view

```
<ListView Width="200">
<ListView.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="Add"   Command="{Binding Path= DataContext.TaskmenuCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" 
                      CommandParameter="Add"/>
   </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

Comment: @abinav_singh what is the name of your window

Comment: i have selected wpf project in vs2013.by default title is MainWindow.so i have given Name="MyWindow".

Comment: @abinav_singh  have you tried my solution?

Comment: It is not working.are you able to simulate this issue .you can add wpf project and copy paste my code.you will also get issue.

Comment: You are using `ListBox` instead of `ListView` in `ContextMenu`

Comment: Make _OpenTaskWindow public.

Comment: @AnjumsKhan sorry copy paste mistake corrected .issue remain same.

Answer (score 0):

try  like this

```
<ListView Width="200" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
  <ListView.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="ContextMenuResourceKey">
      <MenuItem Header="Add" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.TaskmenuCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ListView}}" />
     </ContextMenu>
   </ListView.Resources>
 <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" >
       <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenuResourceKey}" />
     </Style>
 </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
 <ListViewItem Content="Coffie"></ListViewItem>
 <ListViewItem Content="Tea"></ListViewItem>
 <ListViewItem Content="Orange Juice"></ListViewItem>
 <ListViewItem Content="Milk"></ListViewItem>
 <ListViewItem Content="Iced Tea"></ListViewItem>
 <ListViewItem Content="Mango Shake"></ListViewItem>
```

Comment: @abinav_singh  have you changed ElementName= MyWindow

Comment: <MenuItem Header="Add"   Command="{Binding ElementName= MyWindow,Path= DataContext.TaskmenuCommand}" 
                              CommandParameter="Add"/>

Answer (score 0):

There must be some problem with your `RelayCommand`. I created my own `RelayCommand` class as below. My code works with your current XAML.

```
public class ViewModel
    {        
        public RelayCommand TaskmenuCommand
        { get; set; }

        private static void _OpenTaskWindow(object param)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("ViewModel  > " + param.ToString());
        }

        public ViewModel()
        {
            TaskmenuCommand = new RelayCommand(_OpenTaskWindow);
        }
    }

public delegate void CustomFuncDelegate(object parameter);

public class RelayCommand:ICommand
    {            
        public CustomFuncDelegate FuncToExecute { get; set; }

        public RelayCommand(CustomFuncDelegate func)
        {
            FuncToExecute = new CustomFuncDelegate(func);            
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            FuncToExecute(parameter);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Chnage your code as:

```
<ListView Width="200">
<ListView.ContextMenu>
   <ContextMenu>
<MenuItem Header="Add"   Command="{Binding Path= TaskmenuCommand}" 
                      CommandParameter="Add"/>
   </ContextMenu>
</ListView.ContextMenu>
</ListView>
```

> ***You have defined your `ContextMenu` directly in  `ListView`. It will get the same `DataContext` in this case, which is usually not the
>   case with `ContextMenus`.***